# sql geography type and javascript wkt extraction

Tags: javascript, t-sql, openlayers-3

So I have a sql geography type that I use in my sql statement like so:

```
select cast(place.Lat as nvarchar(max)) as latval, cast(place.Long as nvarchar(max)) as longval from table1
```

that ends up like:

```
-29.9747 123.26
```

well on client-side, I have the WKT of that like so:

```
var x = 'POINT (123.26029922486566 -29.974660158941511)';
```

I guess this is more of client-side question because I'd like to **match the exact digits** as what the sql side returns.

I've been trying `substring` but it seems inconsistent based on different coordinates.

In other words, is there a way to have a consistent lat/long format among OpenLayers3, JavaScript, and SQL? (I mentioned OpenLayers because if there's a way here to match SQL output then that would work too. So SQL and OpenLayers or SQL and JavaScript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to cast to nvarchar in sql, instead I casted to a decimal(18,12) and then do all the truncating from JavaScript to be consistent.